# Using construction gypsum instead of plaster of Paris for a substractive plaster sculpture

Tags: material-selection, plaster

For a block-carved sculpture would it be a good idea to use construction gypsum instead of plaster of Paris if I want it to be stronger and more detailed?

Comment: What do you mean by 'construction gypsum' ? The only gypsum I encountered as a carpenter was in sheet form for doing dry-wall. That stuff is extremely weak without its protective paper wrapper.

Comment: If you didn't quite get the information you needed in your first question, you can edit it to update it with some clarifications, or ask comments on the answer. You may need to register your account to do this properly and seamlessly. Asking the question again, is discouraged.